# Defining an excel macro range with a filter applied

Tags: excel, vba

First up, I admit I know almost nothing about writing macro's in excel. I managed to create the macro below from piecing together other macros from various other posts.

The macro below works, but I need it to do one more thing and I cannot figure it out.

Basically, what the macro does is allow the user to select a folder location and then go through a column and pick up the link contained within each row of that column and then save the file on the other end of that link to the folder path selected with a defined naming format.

The only bit that I cannot figure out, is when I apply a filter to the excel form, it will still grab all the files regardless of whether they are visible or not.

The current macro:

```
*Private Declare PtrSafe Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
  "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
    szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim intranetLink As String
Dim mainBook As Workbook
Dim Counter As Integer
Dim saveDialog As FileDialog
Dim savePath As String
Dim filename As String
Counter = 4

    Set saveDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With saveDialog
        .Title = "Select a Folder"              'sticks a title on the dialog so the user kind of knows what they're supposed to be doing
        .AllowMultiSelect = False               'prevents the user from selecting more than one item out the dialog.
        .InitialFileName = strPath              '
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo FolderBombed   'if the user does something funky or cancels, abort the rest of the macro.
        savePath = .SelectedItems(1)            'get the file path to the selected folder
    End With

    For Each vCell In Range("J4:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
    intranetLink = vCell.Text
    filename = Cells(Counter, 6)
        filename = "c:\Path\" + filename
        URLDownloadToFile 0, intranetLink, filename, 0, 0
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Next vCell

FolderBombed:
        MsgBox ("Completed")
End Sub*
```

The line I need to modify is the following one:

```
  For Each vCell In Range("J4:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
```

I have tried changing it to something like this:

```
For Each vCell In Range("J4:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").CurrentRegion.SpecialCells(xlVisible).End(xlUp).Row).
```

but all this does is select a file that is filtered out of the range.

Any help in getting this right would be greatly appreciated.

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this - loop through the cells and check each one:

```
For Each vCell In Range("J4:J" & Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row)
    If not vCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
    [...]
```